# System IO file not found exception C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, filesystems, nopcommerce

So I'm trying to come up with the code to convert a image to base64 version.
But I get a exception thrown.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'C:\content\images\thumbs\0000001_camping_650.jpeg'
```

Now I'm working on a copy of the website on my local machine, but the images are stored on the test server. So I'm fairly sure this is where the problem is coming from.
Also the database is nots tored locally either, but on the sql server.
Both the sql server and test server are public facing.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
string base64String = string.Empty;
// Convert Image to Base64
using (var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Path.GetFullPath(pictureModel.ImageUrl))) // Image Path from File Upload Controller
{
   using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      img.Save(memStream, img.RawFormat);
      byte[] imageBytes = memStream.ToArray();

      // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
      base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
      string ImageBase64 = base64String;
      //   return base64String;
    }
  }
```

Debugging output for this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pictureModel.ImageUrl);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(pictureModel.ImageUrl));
```

is this:

```
/content/images/thumbs/0000001_camping_650.jpeg
C:\content\images\thumbs\0000001_camping_650.jpeg
```

Not sure how to go about solving this one.
Im also working with a bit bucket repository, so the `content\images\thumbs\` directory is excluded from the repository.

My solution on the local machine is C:\projects\test-website so I think I just need to figure out that path and is will work for the test and live site.

Cheers

Comment: Can you debug and check what is the value of `pictureModel.ImageUrl`?

Comment: @Div Thanks for the help, the picture model is built into nopcommerce, and is returning the file name

Comment: Okay, doesn't gives a only file name or file path?

Comment: write a test and create a variable with `Path.GetFullPath(pictureModel.ImageUrl`, inside Unit Test you can test *convert logic* on the file path that is controlled

Comment: Oh sorry that returns this `/content/images/thumbs/0000001_camping_650.jpeg` Updated my question with output from debug

Comment: My solution on the local machine is C:\projects\test-website so I think I just need to figure out that path and is will work for the test and live site.

Comment: @WebDevGuy: You need to add `Server.MapPath("~")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your code as below:

```
string base64String = string.Empty;
// Convert Image to Base64
using (var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~") + pictureModel.ImageUrl))) // Image Path from File Upload Controller
{
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(memStream, img.RawFormat);
        byte[] imageBytes = memStream.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        string ImageBase64 = base64String;
        //   return base64String;
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha beat me by a min, Cheers for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so looks like I figured it out.

First step was to copy all the images into the solution.
Then I needed to use the `Server.MapPath` to get the absolute path to the image.

```
using (var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(pictureModel.ImageUrl))) // Image Path from File Upload Controller
                    {
                        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            img.Save(memStream, img.RawFormat);
                            byte[] imageBytes = memStream.ToArray();

                            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                            base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                            string ImageBase64 = base64String;
                            //   return base64String;
                        }
                    }
```

So now when I do this output:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Server.MapPath(pictureModel.ImageUrl));
```

I get this path:

```
C:\projects\test-website\Presentation\Nop.Web\content\images\thumbs\0000001_camping_650.jpeg
```

I think this will be correct so will accept my answer when I confirm it all works, got another error to figure out now :/

Sigh the joys of coding

Answer (score 0):

If your local machine is not your server machine, you can try to show the path from server to your client machine.

1. Firstly, you need to share your root folder.
2. Then, access your shared folder with server's IP address. For example:

   '\10.0.0.164\content\images\thumbs\0000001_camping_650.jpeg'

Answer (score -2):

If you were testing on your local machine.
Kindly check if that file exist in your local machine

> > 'C:\content\images\thumbs\0000001_camping_650.jpeg'

or check the location of your application where it is located.

Comment: of course, exception is pretty clear. but that is not solution instead.

Comment: This is the problem, the file is not stored on my local machine. It is stored on the test server. and the database holds the path to that file.
Im also working with a bit bucket repository, so the `content\images\thumbs\` diretory is excluded from the repository

Comment: i know that your file path was saved on the server, but you are testing your web app on,local machine.. it is given. so why re create that path in your method. check if that file exists.. or create that folder in local machine and re create it of not existing.